# Java: How do I right justify a $?

Tags: java

Here's what I got:

```
outputStr = name + "\n" + "Gross Amount:$ " + String.format("%.2f", grossAmount) + "\n" 
            + "Federal Tax:$ " + String.format("%.2f", fedIncomeTax) + "\n" + "State Tax:$ "
            + String.format("%.2f", stateTax) + "\n" + "Social Security Tax:$ " + String.format("%.2f", ssTax) 
            + "\n" + "Medicare/Medicaid Tax:$ " + String.format("%.2f", medicareTax) + "\n" + "Pension Plan:$ " 
            + String.format("%.2f", pensionPlan) + "\n" + "Health Insurance:$ " + String.format("%.2f", HEALTH_INSURANCE) 
            + "\n" + "Net Pay:$ " + String.format("%.2f", netPay);
    System.out.println(outputStr);
```

It prints out like this:

```
Random Name 

Gross Amount:$ 3575.00

Federal Tax:$ 536.25
```

And so on...

But I want to right justify the $ and variables 15 spaces to the right, how is this done? I want it like this:

```
Gross Amount:            $3575.00
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I can get the output to right justify by using "%15.2f" but not the $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printf is a good implementation here but string format should work for your purposes.

```
// This will give it 20 spaces to write the prefix statement and then the
//space left will be "tacked" on as blank chars.
String.format("%-20s",prefixStatement); 

//Below is the printf statement for exactly what you want.
System.out.printf("%-20s$%.2f\n","Gross Amount:",3575.00);
//This executes and returns: **Gross Amount:       $3575.00** 

//Below will get you fifteen spaces every time.
String ga = "Gross Amount:";
System.out.printf("%-"+(ga.length()+15)+"s$%d\n","Gross Amount:",2);
//This executes and returns: **Gross Amount:               $2**
```

The idea behind string formatting is you're building a string and then adding in characters to it later through the parameters of String.format and printf. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have the calculations in variables.  I see your putting the number there instead.  Would I just put the variable name there? For your second solution

Comment: Never mind I figured it out.  Thanks for your help the second solution worked great!